# Can't get divs to render properly in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, html, rendering

This webpage I'm building has 10 div classes stacked into two rows (5 on top, 5 on bottom). Each has an image inside. Chrome and Firefox are rendering everything correctly except for one small text phrase that is displaying as a hyperlink when it shouldn't (see bottom of this post for more info). This signals to me that something in my code is off, but I can't for the life of me figure out what. Everything looks normal until I FTP upload it to the live site. Help is much appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div id="text-brands">
      <h2 class="blueheader">Learn More About Our Featured Brands</h2>
      <br />
  <div class="featuredBrands">
   <a href="http://www.attvtedetails.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/Brand Logos/ATT.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="AT&amp;T" /> </a> </div>
    <div class="featuredBrands"><a href="http://www.brotherdetails.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/Brand Logos/BROTHER.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="Brother" /> </div>
    <div class="featuredBrands"><a href="http://www.dymodetails.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/Brand Logos/DYMO.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="Dymo" /></div>
    <div class="featuredBrands"><a href="http://www.fujifilmdetails.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/Brand Logos/FUJI.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="Fuji Film" /> </div>
    <div class="featuredBrands"><a href="http://www.hpdetails.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/Brand Logos/HP.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="HP" /> </div>
    <div class="featuredBrands"><a href="http://www.imation-memorexdetails.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/Brand Logos/IMATION.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="Imation" /> </div>
    <div class="featuredBrands"><a href="http://www.kensingtondetails.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/Brand Logos/KENSINGTON.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="Kensington" /> </div>
    <div class="featuredBrands"><a href="http://www.logitechdetails.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/Brand Logos/LOGITECH.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="Logitech" /> </div>
    <div class="featuredBrands"><a href="http://www.verbatimdetails.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/Brand Logos/VERBATIM.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="Verbatim" /> </div>
    <div class="featuredBrands"><a href="http://www.lexmarkdetails.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/Brand Logos/LEXMARK.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="Lexmark" /> </div>

<br />
<br />
<br />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#text-brands {
   width: 925px;
   float: left;
   padding-top: 30px;
   padding-right: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
   padding-left: 20px;
 }

.featuredBrands {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 10px;
   float: left;
   width: 150px;
   border: 5px solid #EAEAEA;
   clear: none;
   height: 150px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here's the link that I'm having issues with: http://www.officesolutions.com/technology-products.html

Last question (I really just consider this a bonus if someone can help).The far left category at the bottom of the page "Product Categories" is rendering as a hyperlink (specifically, the link that the lexmark logo is supposed to direct to). I can't figure that out, because there is no  markup at all anywhere near that phrase. It's just supposed to be a header, but for some reason is displaying as a link.

HTML:

```
<div id="content-bottom">
          <div id="sitelinks">
            <div class="column" style="border-left: none;">
              <p><strong>Product Categories</strong></p>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="office-supplies.html">Office Supplies</a></li>
                <li><a href="furniture-space-planning.html">Furniture &amp; Space Planning</a></li>
                <li><a href="facility-maintenance-supplies.html">Facility &amp; Maintenance Supplies</a></li>
                <li><a href="coffee-services.html">Coffee Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="printing-promotional-products.html">Printing &amp; Promotional Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="technology.html">Technology</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You are missing closing anchor tags at the end of the images for your first code block. Add them and that could solve your issue. Some of the other browsers take into account errors like that and automatically render appropriately, whereas IE does not. You can also run your code through the W3C Markup Validator and it will tell you where a bunch of your errors are.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused the second and first question seam to be the same about the link carrying over? And can't see anything about display issues in IE9 in your actual question?

The *second question* when inspecting your code there are no closing tags for any of the links in that list.

You may not have the most recent version on there or it may be being stripped out for some very odd reason.

The code as it is:

```
 <div class="featuredBrands"><a href="http://www.attvtedetails.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/Brand Logos/ATT.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="AT&amp;T" /> </a> </div>
        <div class="featuredBrands"><a href="http://www.brotherdetails.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/Brand Logos/BROTHER.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="Brother" /> </div>
        <div class="featuredBrands"><a href="http://www.dymodetails.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/Brand Logos/DYMO.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="Dymo" /></div>
        <div class="featuredBrands"><a href="http://www.fujifilmdetails.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/Brand Logos/FUJI.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="Fuji Film" /> </div>
        <div class="featuredBrands"><a href="http://www.hpdetails.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/Brand Logos/HP.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="HP" /> </div>
        <div class="featuredBrands"><a href="http://www.imation-memorexdetails.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/Brand Logos/IMATION.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="Imation" /> </div>
        <div class="featuredBrands"><a href="http://www.kensingtondetails.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/Brand Logos/KENSINGTON.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="Kensington" /> </div>
        <div class="featuredBrands"><a href="http://www.logitechdetails.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/Brand Logos/LOGITECH.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="Logitech" /> </div>
        <div class="featuredBrands"><a href="http://www.verbatimdetails.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/Brand Logos/VERBATIM.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="Verbatim" /> </div>
        <div class="featuredBrands"><a href="http://www.lexmarkdetails.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/Brand Logos/LEXMARK.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="Lexmark" /> </div>
```

Comment: Wow, I feel really silly now. I forgot to include the closing <a href> tags. After fixing that, everything is displaying correctly. Thanks for catching my simple error! This is probably a sign that I need a break for the day. Thank you, thank you!

Comment: This time of night (In England) there are always silly errors, but we all make them after a long day so to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing closing anchor tags at the end of the images for your first code block. Add them and that could solve your issue. Some of the other browsers take into account errors like that and automatically render appropriately, whereas IE does not. You can also run your code through the W3C Markup Validator and it will tell you where a bunch of your errors are.

Comment: Thank you; the previous commenter also caught that. It was a silly error - everything is now working correctly! :)